# Inconsistencies in Python installation

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, conda

First of all, I do admit that I am not an expert in installing python at all.

I think my python is broken.

**How can I fix Python?**

It is all just a mess of different versions, different interpreters, different environments and conflicts.

I've spent 4 hours this morning, and a few hours last night on this.

Here is a paste of the terminal log: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/a2cwKF5T)

Whatever I try to do to upgrade or create a new environment, it fails.

It all started when I wanted to revisit python again now after a few years.

I've tried so many things so it is impossible to recapitulate what I have done, but it basically goes like this:

I fired up VS code, and tried to select the correct interpreter (3.11.something). Then I tried importing yfinance. This was not a supported module, so I figured I would install it. I launched a new terminal window from VS code and typed

```
pip install yfinance.
```

This invoked downloading a whole bunch of packages. It even seemed like it was downloading every base python from my version and downwards. Anyway, it failed due to some inconsistency. I then realized I was in base python, and using 3.6.something.

I jumped out to a native terminal window, in order to activate a virtual environment and do a pip install there instead.
In order to get the latest python version I decided to do:

```
conda create -n env3 python=3.11.2 anaconda
```

It then gave me the following:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \
```

Which took about 30mins or more, giving me the following:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
```

followed by a whole list of packages and version.
OK,it's above me what to do with that information, so I figured I would update conda and maybe go from there:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

More errors..

I don't know what more to try.

Comment: Are you sure Anaconda supports Python 3.11? They tend to have considerable lag times. Do you actually need the `anaconda` superpackage? It’s soooo many packages most users never need. Users that want frequently updated packages tend to prefer `conda-forge` channel in my experience.

Comment: I manually deleted Anaconda, and command line-installed it again. Now things seems to be working, apart from the Anaconda-Navigator.app launcher in MacOS.